# Apache Thrift: Assign default values to enclosed struct

Tags: struct, thrift, defaults

In an IDL file, I have

```
struct CaseInfo {
    1: CaseID = '',
    2: EvID = 'foobar',
}

struct Case {
    1: CaseInfo CaseInfo,
    2: string key = '',
}
```

When an instance of a Case object is created, CaseInfo is simply null; it doesn't contain a default CaseInfo object. What is the syntax for setting the defaults of such an object?

Comment: you can consult the IDL page http://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl/ , I wouldn't expect it to be possible.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you can initialize default values for structs via a json style map of field names to values.  E.g.

```
struct Case{
    1: CaseInfo CaseInfo = {"CaseID": "", "EvID": "foobar"},
    2: string key = ""
}
```